# Find sequence of text contained in an array (not literal)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, find

I've been searching how to do find text in an array and I can't find a solution. I have loaded a .log file in an array line by line, so I want to do something if any of the lines contains the word "FATAL".

Using Array.contains() doesn't work because it needs to be literal, just a line with FATAL, in that case it works, but the line is something like

```
2018-03-16 00:10:44,937 [API.WebService::logFatal():67] [] FATAL data does not exist.
```

I could loop through the lines and find a string I guess, but the file can be up 100MB so it's not ideal.

```
Dim APIlogger() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\mylog.log")
    If APIlogger.contains("FATAL") Then
        MsgBox("Ooops!")
    End If
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. I am looking at ToLookUp(of) but it seems quite complex to implement.

Comment: Just an update, I manage to solve this by using string.indexof:

`Dim APIlogger() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\mylog.log")

Dim fatalsearch As Integer = APIlogger.IndexOf("FATAL")

If fatalsearch >= 0 Then
MsgBox("FATAL")
End If`

However, I would like to know if this can be done in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can't avoid literate but u can reduce memory usage, using stream reader read line by line, u can always keep last position of file, next time don't read from beginning, try like that..

```
   Using z As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileName)
             ' in case if monitoring file, is good sometimes start from last read point
        If z.BaseStream.Length < lastPoz Then lastPoz = 0 ' reset Position if file is removed or somthing 
        z.BaseStream.Position = lastPoz  ' Set Last Know Position
        Do While z.EndOfStream = False
            Dim LineString = z.ReadLine ' Read Strea line by line , that case dont u can easy handle big file
            If LineString.Contains("FATAL") Then ' Find what u need
                Debug.Print(LineString) ' do somthing
            End If
        Loop
        lastPoz = z.BaseStream.Position ' Remember last Position to future use, next read for log
    End Using
```

u can alweys use linq but in that case u need read all file in to memory.

```
Dim FastalLineList = (From e In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("FILENAME") Where e.Contains("Fatal")).ToList
```

Comment: Zinmniak that's a very smart solution! Thanks for that. What if I want to add to the list the ones that are either FATAL or WARN? I would like to capture both as it's always one line after the other, so I am passing that into a string and displaying it into a listbox to warn the user.